# jQuery: I set a spinner image, then submit the form, but the image doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, forms, spinner

I have a form submit link labeled "OK", and I want to have a spinner to indicate that something is happening when it's clicked.  I tried adding an image to the clicked span before submitting the form, but it doesn't appear:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/img/spinner.gif'>");
    $("#my_form").submit();
}
```

with HTML:

```
<em class="ok_btn">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitMyForm();">OK</a>
</em>
```

It seems like the form submit happens before the page is re-painted.  Is there way to get the page to re-paint, and then submit the form?

Comment: It would probably be better to have a div or some container to add the image to instead of adding the image to the whole page html.

Comment: I'm trying to add the image to the clicked span.  I'll update the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) won't refer to anything because nothing has been passed. I think you need to pass the element to the function with:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitMyForm(this);">OK</a>
```

then the js would become:

```
function submitMyForm(el) {
    $(el).html($(el).html() + "  ");
```

Comment: This was the crux of the matter.  Adding a delay as Diodeus and @Mike Webb suggest is also a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Submitting a form stops ALL other execution. So what's likely happening is your HTML doesn't have time to get updated before your submit action occurs. Try adding a delay:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/img/spinner.gif'>");
   window.setTimeout(function(){ $("#my_form").submit()},500)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$(this).html($(this).html() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/img/spinner.gif'>");
```

To:

```
$('body').append("&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/img/spinner.gif'>");
```

I haven't tested that, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, as I mentioned in my comment, that you probably want to add the image to a div. Something like this:

```
... your html code here ...
<div id="spinnerDiv">
</div>
```

Then add a timeout to the form like this:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    $("#spinnerDiv").html("<img src='/img/spinner.gif'>");
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        $("#my_form").submit();
    }, 500);
}
```